# scanf %p и касты указателей

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer

http://codepad.org/WD1oWXL8

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
  int *p;
  scanf("%p", &p);
  return 0;
}
```

> Line 6: warning: format '%p' expects type 'void**', but argument 2 has type 'int**'

#### Исправляем на явный каст:

http://codepad.org/TR1XEBKP

```
scanf("%p", (void**)&p);
```

> Line 6: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

#### Пробуем `void *`:

http://codepad.org/pH4lUnF5

```
scanf("%p", (void*)&p);
```

> Line 6: warning: format '%p' expects type 'void**', but argument 2 has type 'void*'

#### В итоге скармливаем двойной каст:

http://codepad.org/1UlOShQJ

```
scanf("%p", (void**)(void*)&p);
```

Наконец-то компилируется.

#### Вопрос:

Зачем именно такая диагностика с указателями была добавлена и какие потенциальные проблемы может вызвать чтение указателя, отличного от `void*`?

Comment: А это не смотрели? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686682/scanf-and-the-p-conversion-specifier

Comment: @Unick, там вообще мимо же.

Comment: Гм, VC++ сказал только, что `scanf` функция небезопасная... Да и [тут](http://ideone.com/Hdc47n) без каких бы то ни было предупреждений...

Comment: @Harry, это же gcc'шная аналитика срабатывает. В VS такой вообще нет, а пр остальные компиляторы не в курсе.

Comment: Как Вы себе представляете %p? Это указатель. Но кроме адреса памяти указатель содержит `size`. Хотите указатель на инт? Или на дабл? Как компилятору их различить? Потому и нужна явная конверсия типов

Comment: @DNS, указатель НЕ содержит размер.

Comment: @Qwertiy, поэтому `scanf` и не может определиться с тем, как трактовать введенные данные. - Возможно я не совсем правильно выразился - размер по указателю нужен для передачи данных в память

Comment: Не удаётся получить предупреждение о "type-punned pointer" для второго примера. Версии компиляторов: gcc v6.3.1 и gcc v5.4.0. Может быть, какие-то флаги компиляции надо задавать особые?

Comment: @mymedia, не знаю. А какие на codepad'е? Кроме трактовки предупреждений как ошибок.

Comment: [Нашёл](http://codepad.org/about). Только с этими флагами мой компилятор жалуется на игнорирование возвращаемого значения **scanf**.

Comment: @mymedia, странно, потому что у них не жалуется :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос помечен тагом С++, но все таки для начала пару слов о С:

В языке С указатель типа `int *` формально может иметь объектное представление, отличное от объектного представления указателя типа `void *`. В языке С одинаковыми объектными представлениями обладают только все указатели на `struct` типы (между собой), все указатели на `union` типы (между собой), а также указатели `void *` и `[signed/unsigned] char *` (между собой) (плюс, понятное дело, их cv-квалифицированные вариации). Больше никаких совпадений объектных представлений указателей не гарантируется.

Это означает, что попытка записать значение типа `void *` в указатель типа `int *` через *переинтерпретацию памяти* (type punning) не является формально корректной с точки зрения языка. Язык однозначно говорит, что доступ к объекту типа `int *` как к lvalue типa `void *` любым способом, кроме как через `union`, ведет к неопределенному поведению (см. 6.5/7). Это так называемое правило (или аксиома)  strict aliasing.

Поэтому не существует формально портабельного способа сделать `scanf("%p"` напрямую в указатель типа `int *`. Даже если объектные представления этих типов совпадают, и даже если ваши попытки "задушить" предупреждения компилятора увенчались успехом, это все равно не означает, что ваша программа будет работать корректно. Компилятор, опираясь на вышеупомянутые правила strict alising, имеет полное право полагать, что ваш `scanf("%p"` не модифицирует указатель `p` (ибо он никак не может легально его модифицировать), т.е. игнорировать информационную зависимость между вызовом `scanf` и значением `p`.

Юные "пионэры-практики" из секты "С - это такой портабельный ассемблер" довольно долго умудрялись игнорировать соображения strict aliasing и применяли type punning в своем коде направо и налево, считая это чем-то вроде секретного знания, отличающего их от "теоретиков". Это продолжалось до тех пор пока GCC и другие компиляторы не начали активно использовать в своих оптимизациях ценнейшую информацию, основанную на аксиомах strict aliasing. Вой, поднявшийся в результате из болот "практиков" такого пошиба, окончательно не утих и по сей день. Вот именно от вляпывания в это болото и пытается предохранить вас компилятор своими предупреждениями.

Если вы хотите прочитать значение для вашего `p` через `scanf`, то пожалуй единственный цивилизованный путь - это

```
int *p;
void *v;
scanf("%p", &v);
p = v; // с явным кастом для C++
```

Или, если уж вам неймется устроить type punning, то - через `union`

```
union { int *p; void *v } u;
scanf("%p", &u.v);
p = u.p;
```

Type punning через `union` был таки легализован в C99 (TC3, кажется). Разумеется, с оговоркой, что вся ответственность за корректность получаемого объектного представления ложится на вас.

Вышесказанное имеет прямое отношение и к С++, за исключением того, что type punning через `union` в языке С++ не легализован.

Comment: 1. _"В языке С указатель типа `int *` формально может иметь объектное представление, отличное от объектного представления указателя типа `void *`"_ - а такое реально вообще бывает? 2. _"`scanf("%p"` не модифицирует указатель `p`"_ - прототип scanf'а выглядит как-то так: `int scanf(const char *format, ...)`, поэтому передача `&p` как параметра не нарушает type punning. 3. Разве вариант с union'ом не имеет проблемы, описанные в пункте 1, если всё-таки такая архитектура где-то найдётся?

Comment: @Qwertiy: 1. Навскидку не назову. Однако с некотрой натяжкой можно сказать, что на платформах со строгим отношением к выравниванию (напр. Solaris) тот факт, что младшие биты корректного `int *` указателя должны быть нулевыми, уже представляет собой пример "различия в представлении". Суть-то тут на самом деле не в том, бывает ли так или не бывает, а в том, что strict aliasing правила считают `int *` и `void *` несовместимыми типами.

Comment: 2. Этого пункта я не понял. Если вы передаете куда-то *указатель на `p`*, то ясно, что там `p` могут запросто модифицировать. А если вы передаете туда *неправильно типизированный* указатель на `p`, то все предпосылки для type punning и нарушения strict aliasing наличествуют в полном объеме. К тому же речь-то идет о `scanf`, а не о `printf`. И компилятор запросто может иметь полное представление о семантике `scanf`.

Comment: 3. Опять же, под резрешением type punning через `union` понимается именно и только то, что компилятор не имеет права делать никаких предположений на тему strict aliasing в случае `union`. А в остальном проблемы, разумеется, могут быть и запросто. Но это уже ваша ответственность.

Answer (score 2):

Line 6: warning: format '%p' expects type 'void**', but argument 2 has type 'int**' (хз как красиво выделить желтеньким)

За отображение этой ошибки отвечает флаг -pedantic-errors (он же просто -pedantic). Идем в ман и читаем:
*Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++. For ISO C, follows the version of the ISO C standard specified by any `-std' option used.* бла-бла-бла. Т.е. флаг обеспечивает соответствие кода стандарту для улучшения портируемости на другие платформы/компиляторы.

ISO C++ запрещает неявный каст указателей. 
Идем в ISO C++ и ищем пруф (т.к. на данный момент стандарт уже перевалил за 1500 стр. делать это я конечно не буду).

Далее, ошибка "Line 6: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" за неё ответственен флаг -fstrict-aliasing. Этот флаг указывает компилятору, что объект одного типа никогда не может находится по тому же адресу, что и объект другого типа, кроме случаев, когда это похожие объекты, а void и int это непохожие типы.

В итоге вы пришли к правильному решению, сначала кастим int* к void*, потом void* в void**. 
Хотя я бы написал так:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
{
  void* p = nullptr;
  scanf("%p", &p);
  return 0;
}
```

и кастил бы потом void* куда надо.

Ну и отвечая на вопрос "Зачем именно такая диагностика с указателями была добавлена и какие потенциальные проблемы может вызвать чтение указателя, отличного от void*?". Такая диагностика была добавлена, чтобы программист четко понимал, что, куда и как он кастит (и не мог спихнуть вину на компилятор:)). Про потенциальные проблемы сказать не могу, т.к. ни разу не встречал, чтобы указатели читали scanf'ом, если вы более детально опишите где оно используется, то тогда можно подумать.

P.S. в С такой херни нет, там неявный каст к void разрешен, к слову.
P.P.S. "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" мне кстати получить не удалось на gcc 5.4.0, остальные ошибки успешно повторяются с флагами указанными @mymedia

ссылки:

Флаги g++, -pedantic -fstrict-aliasing
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html

Стандарт ISO C++:
http://open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf

Здесь небольшой тред на тему каста void*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145730/why-does-c-forbid-implicit-conversion-of-void

Хабр, про алиасинг и баги
https://habrahabr.ru/post/114117/

Немного про разыменование и каст указателей непохожих типов
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713851/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-wstrict-ali

Comment: _"ISO C++ запрещает неявный каст указателей"_ - насколько я помню, прототип scanf выглядит как-то так: `int scanf(const char *format, ...)`, соответственно, никакого каста при передаче и быть не может. Это диагностика строки формата и соответствия ей переданных параметров.

Comment: ну да, %p ожидает тип void**